# Salesforce LWC Trying to get the recordId from a lightning-datatable row(s), using the example from the docs & Apex method data returns blank object

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

The lightning-datatable is showing related info to the contact record.

I get the field that changed, with the new data, and the row id, but not the record Id.

Debug logs show I get back a blank Object when trying to add the recordId as per the [Doc for editing multiple rows with Apex.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_inline_edit)

Everything I've googled makes it seem like some magic behind the scenes, but nothing I have tried can get this recordId added correctly. I can see the 'row' has data, but I get back a blank or empty object.

What am I missing?

html snippet

```
<template if:true={isContact}>
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="id"
        data={family}
        columns={petColumns}
        onsave={handleSave}
        draft-values={draftValues}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

js snippet

```
const COLS = [
    {
        label: 'Name',
        fieldName: 'recordUrl',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, 
        target: '_blank'},
        sortable: true
    },
    { label: 'Birthday', fieldName: 'Birthday__c', editable: true, type: 'date-local' },
    { label: 'Type', fieldName: 'Type__c'},
    { label: 'Age', fieldName: 'Age__c', type: 'number', cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' } }
];


async handleSave(event) {
        const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;
        console.log('updatedFields: ' + JSON.stringify(updatedFields))

        // Prepare the record IDs for getRecordNotifyChange()
        const notifyChangeIds = updatedFields.map(row => { 
            console.log('row: ' + JSON.stringify(row))
            return { "recordId": row.Id } });

        // now the object is blank
        console.log('notifyChangeIds: ' + JSON.stringify(notifyChangeIds))

        try {
            // Pass edited fields to the updatePets Apex controller
            const result = await updateRecord({data: updatedFields});
            console.log(JSON.stringify("Apex update result: "+ result));
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Record updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
    
            // Refresh LDS cache and wires
            getRecordNotifyChange(notifyChangeIds);
    
            // Display fresh data in the datatable
            refreshApex(this.pets).then(() => {
            // Clear all draft values in the datatable
            this.draftValues = [];
        });
            
       } catch(error) {
            showToast('Error updating or refreshing records', error.body.message, 'error', 'sticky')
        }
    }
```

Have also tried a method that uses .slice() but the same thing happens, I get a blank object back.

```
const recordInputs =  event.detail.draftValues.slice().map(draft => {
    const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
    return { fields };
});
```

Debug shows:

```
updatedFields: [{"Birthday__c":"2001-06-14","id":"row-0"}]
myTest.js:1 row: {"Birthday__c":"2001-06-14","id":"row-0"}
myTest.js:1 notifyChangeIds: [{}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have put in small case in your markup against key-field. try putting it like key-field="Id". I as capital. could be an api name issue. Hopefully it will resolve.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific? Try do add some code, so others can confirm that your answer works

Answer (score 0):

like @Aksa stated. In the the .html of your component you should set key-field to "Id" instead of "id". The

```html
<template if:true={isContact}>
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="Id"
        data={family}
        columns={petColumns}
        onsave={handleSave}
        draft-values={draftValues}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```